# Installation of the Multi-Device-Hybrid CTP failed to add anything to VS

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I installed the CTP of the multi-device-hybrid apps and the new app templates didn't show up in VS. The add-in also didn't show up in the Extensions & Updates list in VS. Trying to Uninstall it claimed to work instantly, but didn't uninstall anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an odd situation and should generally not occur. It seems the VSIX file got copied over but was not installed correctly.

Here's the work around (run using an administrative command prompt):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common \IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe" /admin /uninstall:MultiDeviceHybridApps..db151788-9b27-49db-a5e2-d25a2653eb83
```

This removed the broken entries for the VSIX from the previous failed attempt to install.  Following this, issue another command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe" "%localappdata\Microsoft\MultiDeviceHybridApps\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.vsix" /admin
```

At this point, the VSIX should be installed successfully and the templates will become available in Visual Studio.