# Multi-Device-Hybrid installation maybe fails

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installation, visual-studio-cordova

I installed the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps (Preview) from here 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=397606

i had problems in the first installation, because the VS2013 show the same screen for hours, with it i restar the pc and start a repair the installation... but looks like this is not installed because i don´t have projects templates for this type of apps and in tool optins i have this result:
[image]

Someone can help with it? I just did 2 repairs.... :/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your installation did not complete successfully, which is why the project template does not show up. Its hard to tell what went wrong. However, repairing a failed install will probably not help get things running.

Could you try running the [installer](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=397606) again and see if that works.

Comment: i run the install again that show some option: modify, repair and uninstall. I did repair for more than 3 times and did not worked. will try the modify

Comment: i did a modify and don´t have nothing for modify and i tried to remove and it not removed nothing....lol the solution is remove all about visual studio 2013 and then install again...maybe

Comment: .@saramgsilva - there are cases when the extension fails to install even though the installer completes successfully. Could you try the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686482/installation-of-the-multi-device-hybrid-ctp-failed-to-add-anything-to-vs.

Comment: i tried that, but fails...not worked too :( in this pc i have Visual Studio Professional 2013, in home have Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and don´t have problems

Comment: Could you email the team at multidevicehybridapp@microsoft.com and we can try to debug your case.

Comment: Thanks! :D just sent it